# Receive syntax error when installing gem on Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm trying to install a gem using Ruby. I keep getting a weird syntax error when I do. Using rvm, latest version, to install. The error message is:

```
  /Users/george/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 30 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /Users/george/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:333:in `load_file'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:198:in `initialize'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `do_configuration'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

I also get this error when trying to set rvm to use a different ruby version.

Comment: What gem are you trying to install?

Comment: unixoid-challenge for my coding bootcamp, but gem gets the same error

Comment: What do you mean by `but gem gets the same error`? What command/commands are you running? We can't help you if you can't describe the problem with sufficient detail.

Comment: I think he means that the same error is generated when trying to install the gem?

Comment: Ah sorry! I meant: "but any gem gets the same error" - i.e. if I try to install any kind of gem then it gives me this error. So if I run "gem install rails" or something then the error is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there was an issue in the `.gemrc` file as well as some other files created in the root folder that were affecting RVM from installing Ruby correctly.

Re-storing the files to the previous state and removing the junk files with `rm -rf` got everything working.

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your rubygems config file. If you're not using a custom config file, look for a file `.gemrc` in your home folder. It seems there's incorrect content on line 2.

Psych is a YAML parser, so look for something that is incorrect YAML.